# amending a commit after it has been pushed

Tags: git, commit, git-amend

In my most recent commit to my repository that has already been pushed, I noticed I misspelled a single word in a file and now would like to change it. However, I do not want to create a whole new commit. Is there a way to amend my latest commit and push that into my repository without having to reset, remove, and push?

In the past I did:

```
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
git push -f
# correct the spelling
git add .
git commit -m "bug10 fix"
```

Is there a way to correct the spelling of the file, amend my latest commit and push without having to reset, force remove, then re-commit?

I tried:

```
# fixed the file
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push
```

```
 ! [rejected]        Nov21 -> Nov21 (non-fast-forward)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's impossible to change *any* commit.  That includes *before it's pushed*.  The reason this is important to know—the reason you need to know that `git commit --amend` is a lie—is that what `git commit --amend` does locally, *can* be done here when pushing a commit to another Git repository.

The (tiny) lie with `git commit --amend` is that it *didn't* change a commit at all.  It just *seemed* to do that.  What it really did was make a *new and improved replacement commit*.

You can do this any time you like.  You just need to know that each commit is *numbered*—every commit has a *unique* number, which is its *hash ID*—and that Git *finds* commits in a sort of backwards (perhaps even [backassward](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backassward)) fashion, by having a *branch name* or other name locate the *most recent* commit for you, and then working backwards from there.

Imagine a simple chain of commits, ending with your most recent commit whose hash is some big ugly random-looking hash ID that we'll just call `H`.  Here's how *Git* sees—and finds—these commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--your-branch
```

Your branch name "points to" (contains the hash ID of) commit `H`.  Commit `H` itself contains the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  (Commit `H` also contains a full snapshot of every file, though we won't look at this at all here.)

Commit `G`, being a commit, is numbered by some big ugly random-looking hash ID, and has a snapshot and metadata and hence points backwards to still-earlier commit `F`.  That's a commit so it's numbered and has the same kind of stuff and points backwards yet again, and so on.

Now, if you have a tiny typo in commit `H` and run `git commit --amend`, what Git does is to make a *new commit*.  The new commit is exactly like `H` except in two ways:

- it has a different hash ID, so let's call it `I`; and
- it has the typo corrected.

Commit `H` is *still there in your repository*.  It's just no longer used.  `H` still points back to `G`, but so does new commit `I`:

```
            H   ???
           /
... <-F <-G <-I   <--your-branch
```

Git updates your *branch name* to point to new commit `I`.  This effectively "kicks `H` off the branch", because Git *finds* commits by starting at the end and working backwards.

Now, if you ran `git push`, what you did was *send commit `H` to another Git repository*, and then have them update one of *their* branch names—probably the same name you're using in your repository—to point to the now-shared commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <--their-branch
```

If you make a new commit `I` that's a new-and-improved *replacement for* `H` and just send it to them with a regular `git push`, they'll take the commit and put it into their repository temporarily:

```
          H   <--their-branch
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I
```

and then you have your Git ask their Git to set *their* branch name to point to `I` too.

The problem comes in here, because when you do that, they check: *If I update my branch name to point to `I`, do I lose any commits off the end?*  And of course they *do:* they lose commit `H` off the end of their branch.  That's what you *want* them to do—that's what *your* Git did with *your* `git commit --amend`, after all—but *they don't know that*.  All they know at this point is that they do have `H` and you're asking them to drop it now.

You can use:

```
git push --force
```

or:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

to send them a *command*, instead of a polite request, that tells them that they *definitely should* make their name point to `I` (regular `--force`), or that you think their name points to `H` now and if so they should make it point to `I` instead (`--force-with-lease`).  If they will take such commands from you—most hosting sites, like GitHub and Bitbucket and GitLab have fancy configurations they add atop Git to control these things—then this lets you replace `H` with `I` after all.

#### Why you might use `--force-with-lease`

Note that if the hosting site is taking `git push` requests from *other people*, they might by now have:

```
          H--J--K   <--their-branch
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I
```

and hence your command that they set their branch to point to `I` will drop not just your commit `H`, but also these other two additional commits `J-K`, off the end of their branch.

Using `git push --force-with-lease` sends them your new commit `I` but also sends them the hash ID `H` that you believe they have as their final commit on their branch.  If your belief is wrong, your conditional command—that they must change their name to point to `I` instead—gets a rejection that says your Git is now out of date, and you need to run `git fetch` first.

If this *can't* happen, you don't need `--force-with-lease`.  Very old Git versions don't *have* `--force-with-lease` either, but all modern ones do and it's usually wisest to keep the safety check in place even if it's not necessary, since "habits" may become "bad habits" over time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed response!

Comment: Further complication - if other people have pulled `H` into their local repos, and perhaps started working on top of it, you'll have to email them all and ask them to rebase their work on `I`. They'll be quite annoyed if you do this for a simple typo that could've been fixed in another commit... so only do this if there's basically nobody else using the repo, or if the problem is a major one which warrants this kind of disruption.

Comment: @JiříBaum: yes, this is why the general rule for rebase or amend (which are fundamentally the same) is that all who might be affected by this should have agreed to having this done, before it's done.

Comment: @torek, hey man tnx, you have really explained it nicely

Comment: Wow. Bravo . I absolutely love this answer. Now I see where the problem came from

Comment: Hey, great answer .Towards the end you said '"need to run git fetch first" in case the branch has had additional commits. In such case how does it work. If I push my amended commit then what happens to that old commit 5 steps back?

Comment: Loved this answer. Since I am on my own project, I just pushed with `--force`. The problem is the branch is protected (well, it's my own project but it is supposed to be shared). So I had to pull, solve conflicts and add|commit|push again. Is there a better way to do that?