# how to remove a renamed file from last git commit?

Tags: git, rename, git-commit, undo

I know how to

- [Remove files from last git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126851/remove-files-from-last-git-commit)
- [Remove a file change from a git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282824/remove-a-file-change-from-a-git-commit)

but what I want is to exclude the renamed file from last git commit, but retain anything else (as `git mv` get into my commit unintentionally).

How can I do that?

(Seems I can only revert everything or not at all...)

Comment: You cannot change a commit. It's unclear from your description what the precise problem is.

Comment: A move is just a deletion and a creation, so this is the same as separately reverting each of a deletion and a creation, if that helps. (You can also just move it back and amend the commit.)

Comment: see: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the internet for "git how can I change my latest commit content", you will find documentation pages such as :

- [Git commit --amend and other methods of rewriting history](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history) (atlassian.com)
- [How can I add a file to the last commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503417/how-can-i-add-a-file-to-the-last-commit-in-git) (SO)
- [amending a commit after it has been pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051009/amending-a-commit-after-it-has-been-pushed) (SO)

---

One generic way to "change the latest commit" is to edit files and `git add` them as you want, then run `git commit --amend`.

This works for any kind of modifications: the commit will simply contain the new content you `git add`ed.

For example:

- to "undo" a `git mv old.txt new.txt`:

```
git mv new.txt old.txt
git commit --amend
```

- to still remove `old.txt` but not add `new.txt` in the commit:

```
git rm --cached new.txt  # --cached will make git keep the file on disk
git commit --amend
```

- to edit a typo:

```
# edit file foo.txt ...
git add foo.txt
git commit --amend
```

etc ...